# Using Non-Rest Calls with Loopback (Strongloop)

Tags: node.js, rest, express, loopbackjs, strongloop

We're using Loopback for our REST apis and would like to implement some standard Node Express-like calls through the same instance that do not get automatically routed through the Loopback framework. How can we add a new, separate route without disturbing the Loopback routing? Here's the standard Loopback startup code:

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');

var app = module.exports = loopback();

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.
boot(app, __dirname);

app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', app.get('url'));
  });
};

// start the server if `$ node server.js`
if (require.main === module) {
  app.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it via middleware in `server/server.js` as you would normally do in a typical Express app.

```
...
// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.
boot(app, __dirname);

app.use('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
});
....
```

Comment: I'm getting errors after adding that route: Loopback
500 TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'send'
   at app.start (C:\Dev\Projects\as\as.server\server\server.js:11:9)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]

Comment: Which LoopBack version do you use? Make sure the latest version is installed. We fixed a similar bug before.

Comment: Just upgraded to LoopBack version: 2.10.2.  We're now getting the following error: 500 TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'send'
   at app.start (C:\Dev\Projects\as\as.server\server\server.js:11:9)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]

Comment: The console.log works so the code is executing. However, it's breaking on res.send.

app.use('/', function (res, req) {
    console.log('hello, world');
    res.send('hello world');
});

Comment: There is a bug in the code provided by superkhau. The correct one should be: app.use('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
});

Comment: Woops, just noticed req and res were backwards. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try and let you know.